# JQuery wrong ID in an inner click

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

I'm trying to make a colorpicker. Where you got a few colorcubes with the class colorcube.
When clicking, it opens a colorpicker with a few list items who all have a different color.
When clicking on a list items it should return de color/text to de colorcube.

The first colorpick after the document is ready works. But after that it doesnt work properly, because it remembers al the previous colorcube ID's so al the other cube's will also change :(

Is there a way to clear cache or something like that?

```
$('.colorcube').click(function() {
    var colorcubeid = $(this).attr("id");
    $('#choicecolor').show();

    $(".li_color").click(function() {
        var colorid = "#" + this.id;
        var colorli = $(colorid).text();
        $('#' + colorcubeid).text(colorli);
        $('#' + colorcubeid).css({ 'background-color': '' + colorli + '' });
        $('#choicecolor').hide();
        savecolor();
    });

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're assigning redundant `click` event handlers with every click on `colorcube`. You should assign the handlers only once.

It seems like you're doing this in order to reference the ID of the `colorcube` that was clicked. You could use a variable instead to track which was clicked.

```
var $currentCube,
    $choiceColor = $('#choicecolor');

$('.colorcube').click(function() {
    $currentCube = $(this);
    $choiceColor.show();
});

$(".li_color").click(function() {
    var colorli = $(this).text();
    $currentCube.text(colorli)
                .css({ 'background-color': colorli });
    $choiceColor.hide();
    savecolor();
});
```

I made a number of changes as well.

Instead of referencing just the ID of the current color cube, I'm referencing the actual element wrapped in a jQuery object, so you can just call methods on it directly.

This code:

```
var colorid = "#" + this.id;
var colorli = $(colorid).text();
```

...is much more complex than needed, since you can just do:

```
var colorli = $(this).text();
```

...where `this` is the `<li>` that was clicked.

You don't need:

```
'' + colorli + ''
```

because `colorli` is already a String. Just do

```
.css({ 'background-color': colorli })
```

As [@Šime Vidas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/425275/sime-vidas) noted, you should cache the `$('#choicecolor');` so that you're not constantly selecting it from the DOM.

```
var $currentCube,
    $choiceColor = $('#choicecolor');
```

I also used chaining on this line. With jQuery you don't really need to separate your function calls against the same jQuery object. They can be chained together.

```
$currentCube.text(colorli)
            .css({ 'background-color': colorli });
```

Comment: @patrick +1 While you're at it, you can cache the #choicecolor jQuery object ( `var $choicecolor = $("#choicecolor")` ) because otherwise you're selecting it unnecessarily on every click.

Comment: @Šime Vidas: Absolutely. :o) Good call.

Comment: Wow! That was really helpfull! I was trying to fix it for the last 2 days. Also Thx for the adjusments! I'll keep on learning new stuff :-)

Comment: Thx Šime! I'll be here more often now :)

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to untangle why you need the nested click functions. Seems like you should be able to un-nest them. You may have to add a bit of jquery to get the 'colorcubeid' in the second function.

I believe what is happening is that the 'colorcubeid' variable is in the scope of the inner click function and is never being updated.

Bob

Answer (score 0):

You need to [unbind](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) your previous click-handlers, so that they won't be called again.

However I would recommend to avoid that and create a clean instance of the `#choicecolor` via jQuery templates or similar approaches - saves you a lot of headaches if you do not recycle your control over and over again.